# How can I convert a tuple of floats to integers without having to convert each individual tuple element in Python?

Tags: python, casting, tuples

I have this code in Python:

```
self.__color = (int(f * c[0] * Li[0]), int(f * c[1] * Li[1]), int(f * c[2] * Li[2]))
```

How can I convert each element of the tuple to an int instead of having to cast each element like I do above?

I want to do something like:

```
int((float, float, float)) --> (int, int, int)
```

Comment: `tuple(map(int, tuple_of_floats)`

Comment: your last element `int(f * c[2] * Li[2], 0)` should be : `int(f * c[2] * Li[2])` ?

Comment: @kederrac Corrected it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generator

```
self.__color = (int(x) for x in (f * c[0] * Li[0], f * c[1] * Li[1], f * c[2] * Li[2], 0))
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could use that syntax for tuples